# Regular expression for a list of elements in patents

Tags: python, regex

Given a patent, how do you produce a regular expression that will filter out the element list in the description? Elements can be identified by:

1. 'a' or 'the' before the **element**
2. a digit after the element

For example, given this paragraph:

> 'FIG. 1 shows a base 10 for an adjustable cord holding device according to an embodiment of the present invention.  The base 10 may comprise a base hole 16 to allow a cord to pass through the base 10.  The shape of the base hole 16 depends on the intended use of the adjustable cord holding device.  If the cross section of the cord is round, the base hole 16 may also be round.  On the other hand, when the intended cord is a belt, whose cross section is rounded rectangle, the base hole 16 may also be rounded rectangle.'

I would like to use a regular express to spit out

```
['a base 10', 'The base 10', 'a base hole 16', 'the base 10', 'the base hole 16', 'the base hole 16', 'the base hole 16']
```

Comment: Why not `a base`? Also regular expression extract a regular result but your expected result is not regular!!! I mean you didn't specify a correct definition for `noun` some times you have 1 word some time you have 2 ...!!

Comment: @Kasra: Propably because of `the base hole 16`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Modified accordingly to define what a noun is.

Comment: @albert So in that case it wont be a regex task anymore!

Comment: @Kasra: Yep, in this case, you're absolutely correct. The given search criteria seem not to be regular anyway...

Comment: Why not search for substrings to solve that two-word problem?

Comment: @Kasra Maybe it's not possible, just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @bcdan I'm sure this is not limited to one or two words. I thought that there was a possibility that a regular expression could match the (?i)(a|the) and the digit afterwords to spit out the desired result.

Comment: And then there are things like adjectives.....

Comment: What about matching the desired element with the word before and after it in three different group. If the first group contains 'the' or 'a' extract the third group containing the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()` :

```
>>> re.findall(r'((?:a|the)(?:(?!(?:\ba\b|\bthe\b)).)*\d+)',s,re.I)
['a base 10', 'The base 10', 'a base hole 16', 'the base 10', 'the base hole 16', 'the base hole 16', 'the base hole 16']
```

The following regex :

```
r'((?:a|the)((?!(?:\ba\b|\bthe\b)).)*\d+)
```

will match any sub string that starts with `a` or `the` and ends with a digit.but between them `((?!(?:\ba\b|\bthe\b)).)*` which used a [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will match anything except the words `a` and `the`. for get ride of long matches like `'the present invention. The base 10'`  and use `re.I` flag for ignoring the case!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Deciphering this will be fun.

Comment: if my input is `FIG. 1 illustrates one instance of a portable consumer electronic device (or “mobile device”) in which an embodiment of the invention may be implemented. As shown in FIG. 1, the mobile device 1 may be a mobile telephone communications device or a smartphone such as`. My result ends up being `('the invention may be implemented. As shown in FIG. 1', 'the mobile device 1')`

Comment: following your regex, if I add `fig` to the negative lookahead, `l=re.findall(r'((?:a|the)((?!(?:\ba\b|\bthe\b|\bfig\b)).)*\d+)',description,re.I)` I'll end up with an extra empty result. `>>> print l
[('the mobile device 1', ' ')]`

Comment: @warpandas The result is as should be! so what you expected?